# Center navbar List elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp, menubar

I am creating a navigation bar using an unordered list. I want my list elements (element1, element2) to be written in center of the box created outside them.

```
-----------                                                       -------------    
   el1          whereas presently it is coming to the right like            el1 
-----------                                                        ------------
```

HTML:

```
<div id="central-section" class="central-section-base">
            <div id="ddtopmenubar" class="mattblackmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" rel="ddsubmenu1">Element 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" rel="ddsubmenu2">Element 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" rel="ddsubmenu3">Element 3</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.mattblackmenu ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
font: bold 12px Verdana;
list-style-type: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
background:     #153E7E;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

.mattblackmenu li{
display: table;
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
text-align:center;  
}

.mattblackmenu li a{
float: left;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 6px 8px; /*padding inside each tab*/
border-right: 1px solid white; /*right divider between tabs*/
color: white;
background:     #153E7E;
}
```

I am also using Horizontal Nav Plugin (http://sebnitu.github.io/HorizontalNav/).

Comment: need more explanation. put a screenshot/fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this css editing...

```
.mattblackmenu li { 
 width: 100%; /*new edit*/
 }

.mattblackmenu li a 
  { float:right; /*editing left to right*/
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly your question,
 but if you want the items are one next to another in the middle of the container
You could use this css code [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/HWb8E/)

```
.mattblackmenu ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
font: bold 12px Verdana;
list-style-type: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
background:     #153E7E;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

.mattblackmenu li{
display: table;
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;  
}

.mattblackmenu li a{
float: left;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 6px 8px; /*padding inside each tab*/
border-right: 1px solid white; /*right divider between tabs*/
color: white;
background: #153E7E;

}
```

To add a small white bar in front of the first link you should also add this selector to your css code

```
.mattblackmenu li:first-of-type{
border-left: 1px solid white;   
}
```